# Square of each element of a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How can I square each element of a column/series of a DataFrame in pandas (and create another column to hold the result)?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]], columns=list('ab'))
>>> df
   a  b
0  1  2
1  3  4
>>> df['c'] = df['b']**2
>>> df
   a  b   c
0  1  2   4
1  3  4  16
```

Comment: As of June 2023 I noticed that using the integer power `df['b']**2` delivers a wrong result, while adding a point to the power and making it a float (`df['b']**2.`) delivers the desired correct answer. Am I mistaken? Why is this the case?

Comment: Can you describe more clearly what "wrong" means?  "Off by a minimal amount"? or "results in cube instead of square" or something else?

Answer (score 33):

Nothing wrong with the accepted answer, there is also:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(0,100)})
np.square(df)
np.power(df, 2)
```

Which is ever so slightly faster:

```
In [11]: %timeit df ** 2
10000 loops, best of 3: 95.9 µs per loop

In [13]: %timeit np.square(df)
10000 loops, best of 3: 85 µs per loop

In [15]: %timeit np.power(df, 2)
10000 loops, best of 3: 85.6 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 9):

You can also use [`pandas.DataFrame.pow()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pow.html) method.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2], [3,4]], columns=list('ab'))
>>> df
   a  b
0  1  2
1  3  4
>>> df['c'] = df['b'].pow(2)
>>> df
   a  b   c
0  1  2   4
1  3  4  16
```

Comment: As I commented above, now (June 2023) using the integer power `.pow(2)` delivers a wrong result, while adding a point to the power and making it a float (`.pow(2.)`) delivers the desired correct answer. Am I mistaken? Why is this the case?